# saving images to static folder require refresh/reload the server to implement changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to save/load images in the `resource/public/images` folder of my spring boot project, but I faced a problem that all changes to this folder require to restart of the tomcat server but I need to implement all changes without restarting anything to avoid production problems.
I searched for a solution on the Internet and I reached to use additional tools that should be a solution to my problem so I used `devtool` dependency but I still have the problem.
I'm not looking for local changes on my IDE but I need a solution that can be work everywhere.

Comment: as the folder name states, this is a folder for *static* content. Take another folder to put your dynamic content in

Comment: I have tried to but my files in other folders like public, images but still have the same problem

Comment: as i'm trying to reach this file from server like this (localhost:8081/images/pic.jpeg) it wont take this uploaded image until restarting the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the solution that you are looking for is not possible and should not be design like that. Think of it, when your application would be ready, it would be a jar/war (an archived library) deployed on production and its not expected that your jar/war has to have changed at runtime. The correct solution would be, on the same server where you would deploy you app, you can create a folder (may be in same directory where you place your jar) and in this folder you can manage your images and can be read from there. So try by creating a folder outside your app.
And for your local, devtool is basically consume the latest changes from code and helpful only for development as you don't want to restart the server every time when you make any changes in the code.

Comment: Hi, so you suggest to save images in a database? Because I want to work with dynamic images that the user can create/upload but I'm not so sure how to create a folder where I deploy my app (with docker), do you have any example for that? thanks!